# User won't navigated to app store on dynamic link tap even if isi parameter is specified

Tags: flutter, app-store, firebase-dynamic-links

Firebase dynamic link is being constructed inside a Flutter application with the next options:

```
iosParameters: IosParameters(
            bundleId: Deeplinks.iosPackageName,
            appStoreId: Deeplinks.appleStoreId)
```

, whereas `Deeplinks.appStoreId` points to a valid application's id in store. And even if the value is changed to point to Facebook app (`284882215`) the link would navigate to the inner dynamic link's link (the actual link that the application would receive if installed, the one that is being passed as the [link](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_dynamic_links/lib/src/dynamic_link_parameters.dart#L20) parameter in `DynamicLinkParameters` object's constructor), which results into 404 code being sent back to the client.

Why does it open the inner link and how to get Apple devices to be redirected to the AppStore's application page?